# Dynamic Implementation of Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
class Nodetype
{
  int info;
  Nodetype next;

  Nodetype(int i)
  {
     info=i;
     next=null;
  }
}
```

My textbook has this code to create Linked List dynamically.
The question is, when the programs is executed line-by line, it defines variable 'info' as type 'int' & then variable 'next' as Nodetype.

What is actually happening here?

does it mean that variable 'next' will contain -

1. Constructor 'Nodetype'
2. int info
3. Nodetype "next" where "next" will again have all 1,2,3 & then 3 will again have 1,2,3...and so on....till infinity?

I'm really irritated because I'm unable to understand how it works, can someone easily explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first variable `next` doesn't point to any object(it points to `null`). At some time you will make it point to another node with `next = new NodeType(number)`. The idea is that you use composition - you have one instance of class which has a reference to another instance. It is like `nodeA` points to `nodeB`, `nodeB` points to `nodeC`. Here you have three instances and the first instance has a reference to the second instance and the second instance has a reference to the third instance. The third instance is the **last** one and its next instance points to `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code follows very well the definition of list: a list is `null` or an element followed by a list.
The "element", in your case, is defined by an `int` value, and the "followed by" part is the `next` variable; in Java variables (when they are not literals, as `int` values are) are actually pointers, so while they are not initialized they don't store any valid value and they don't point to any memory area (i.e. their value is `null`), so while the `next` variable is kept as-is your element is not followed by any other. To dynamically add elements to your list you need a pointer to the last element you added, otherwise you would not be able to find them again:

```
int i = 0;
Nodetype head = new Nodetype(i++);
Nodetype last = new Nodetype(i++);
head.next = last;
while (i<5) {
    Nodetype temp = new Nodetype(i++);
    last.next = temp;
    last = temp;
}
while(head) {
    System.out.println(head.info);
    head = head.next;
}
```

Notice how, with the last few lines, you lose the `head` pointer and you have no way to get back the starting point of your list.. Keep that in mind when working with lists ;)

Answer (score 1):

the field `next` is a reference to an object of type `Nodetype`. at first it will point to nothing - since it is instantiated to `null`. when you assign a value to it, it will point to that value only, nothing will continue infinitely unless you create a cycle within the list.

Answer (score 1):

You created class `NodeType` and inside of the class you defined object of that class. So that object (in your example `next`) will have `int info` variable `NodeType next` object and constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`next` is a reference to another `Nodetype` instance. If `next == null` it means the current element is the last one in the list.

Let's see an example:

```
Nodetype node = new Nodetype(0);        // i = 0, next = null
Nodetype anotherNode = new Nodetype(1); // i = 1, next = null
node.next = anotherNode;                // now the first node has a ref to the second
```

Answer (score 1):

It will contain Null, as the variable is not initialized to any value.

Answer (score 1):

`Nodetype` is your class that defines the data a node instance will contain as well as the reference to the next node in the linked list. That reference to the next node will be an object of type `Nodetype`. Nothing too difficult here, this is the classic implementation of a Linked List.

You might want to check out this [great linked list resourc](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf)e from Stanford.

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is that the list is made up of single elements, each of which only has a pointer to the one that comes after it:

```
Nodetype next;
```

The information each element within the list actually holds is this:

```
int info;
```

You can think of a list like a "chain": it's not really a single object, but a compound object of a number of links. From each link, you can only see the next link (or, in case of linked lists that have references in both directions: the next and the previous link), so in order to have all elements available, you will have to keep the reference to the first element in the "chain".

Note: `List` objects are single objects that have a reference to the first link of the "chain".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void print_list(int *arr,int *size,int *capacity)
{
     printf("capacity = %d; size = %d; elements = ",*capacity,*size);
     for(int i=0;i<(*size);i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
     printf("\n");
}

int * push_back(int *arr,int data,int *size,int *capacity)
{
    int *b;
    if(*size == *capacity){

        *capacity = 2*(*capacity);
        b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*capacity));

        for(int i=0;i<(*size);i++){
        b[i]= arr[i];
        }
        b[*size]=data;
        *size=*size+1;
        print_list(b,size,capacity);
        return b;
    }

     arr[*size]=data;
     *size=*size+1;
     print_list(arr,size,capacity);

     return arr;
}
int main()
{
     int size=0;
     int n;
     int x;
     int *arr;
     arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
     int capacity=1;

     scanf("%d",&n);

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&x);
        arr=push_back(arr,x,&size,&capacity);
     }
}
```

its working.